WebRTC fetchUserIpAddress works on localhost but fails in production
I'm using the following code to fetch the user's IP address on my website. It works perfectly on localhost, but when I deploy it live, it doesn't return any IP addresses.
I want to avoid relying on third-party services. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it so that it works in both localhost and live environments?
export const fetchUserIpAddress = (): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        const rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] });
        rtc.createDataChannel("");
        rtc.createOffer()
            .then((offer) => rtc.setLocalDescription(offer))
            .catch((error) => reject(error));
        rtc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
            if (!event || !event.candidate) {
                reject("No IP addresses found");
                return;
            }

            const candidate = event.candidate.candidate;
            const ipRegex =
                /([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}[a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}/;
            const ipMatch = candidate.match(ipRegex);

            if (ipMatch) {
                resolve(ipMatch[0]);
            } else {
                reject("No IP addresses found");
            }
        };
    });
};


WebRTC is built for video conferencing, not to allow you to gather a users IP address without their consent. Therefore you only get a useless temporary mdns hostname ending in .local from the API which does not match your filter.
This blog post from five years ago tells you more: https://bloggeek.me/psa-mdns-and-local-ice-candidates-are-coming/
